# React with Rails 7: Could not resolve "../components/EditTopic"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I'm very used to Rails but am adding React as a front-end for the first time and am hitting what I hope are very obvious beginner issues.  I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-v7-project-with-a-react-frontend-on-ubuntu-20-04) (roughly...with my own model structure), but it doesn't actually go over adding edit routes.  (It's more CRD than CRUD for some reason...)

I have the following routes set up in my `javascript/routes/index.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import MainNavbar from "../components/MainNavbar";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Topics from "../components/Topics";
import Topic from "../components/Topic";
import NewTopic from "../components/NewTopic";


export default (
  <Router>
    <MainNavbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/topics" element={<Topics />} />
      <Route path="/topic/:id" element={<Topic />} />
      <Route path="/topic" element={<NewTopic />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);
```

With this structure, it works perfectly fine.  However, when I add a route for `EditTopic` it disappears from the page and a server error pops up:

> 19:50:16 js.1   | [watch] build started (change:
> "app/javascript/routes/index.jsx") 19:50:16 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could
> not resolve "../components/EditTopic" 19:50:16 js.1   |  19:50:16 js.1
> |     app/javascript/routes/index.jsx:8:22: 19:50:16 js.1   |       8
> │ import EditTopic from "../components/EditTopic";

The routes I am adding are pretty simple.  I use:

```
import EditTopic from "../components/EditTopic";
```

And for the actual route I have tried both:

```
  <Route path="/topics/:id" element={<EditTopic />} />
```

And:

```
  <Route path="/topics/:id" element={<EditTopic />} />
```

Both create the same error.  Can anyone help out as to where I'm going wrong?

### EDIT

I've got an initial `EditTopic.jsx` set out based on the `NewTopic.jsx` that actually works.  I know it's probably full of errors, but I was going to learn/debug using this as a template:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const EditTopic = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [definitions, setDefinitions] = useState("");
  const [state_v_trait, setStateVTrait] = useState("");
  const [measurement, setMeasurement] = useState("");
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");

  const stripHtmlEntities = (str) => {
    return String(str)
      .replace(/\n/g, "<br> <br>")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  };

  const onChange = (event, setFunction) => {
    setFunction(event.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = "/api/v1/topics/${this.state.id}";

    if (name.length == 0 )
      return;

    const body = {
      name: stripHtmlEntities(name),
      definitions: stripHtmlEntities(definitions),
      state_v_trait: stripHtmlEntities(state_v_trait),
      measurement: stripHtmlEntities(measurement),
      notes: stripHtmlEntities(notes)
    };

    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
    })
    .then((response) => navigate(`/topic/${response.id}`))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };


  // CUE HTML
  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
          <h1 className="font-weight-normal mb-5">
            Edit {name}.
          </h1>
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="topicName">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="topicName"
                className="form-control"
                required
                onChange={(event) => onChange(event, setName)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="topicDefinitions">Definitions</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="definition"
                id="topicDefinitions"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(event) => onChange(event, setDefinitions)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="state_v_trait">State versus Trait</label>
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                id="state_v_trait"
                name="state_v_trait"
                rows="5"
                onChange={(event) => onChange(event, setStateVTrait)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="measurement">How is this measured?</label>
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                id="measurement"
                name="measurement"
                rows="5"
                onChange={(event) => onChange(event, setMeasurement)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="notes">Other Notes</label>
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                id="notes"
                name="notes"
                rows="5"
                onChange={(event) => onChange(event, setNotes)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn custom-button mt-3">
              Create Topic
            </button>
            <Link to="/topics" className="btn btn-link mt-3">
              Back to topics
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  // END HTML

};

export default NewTopic;
```

However, I have also tried it with this very stripped-down version of `EditTopic.jsx` and the error still persists:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const EditTopic = () => {

};

export default NewTopic;
```

Comment: Can you show your EditTopic component?

Comment: @tpliakas It's been added.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Your export has the wrong name. ````export default NewTopic```` should be ````EditTopic````

Comment: @tpliakas Always the small, moronic stuff.  Thank you!

Comment: Cool! Will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your export has the wrong name.

```
export default NewTopic
```

should be

```
export default EditTopic
```